# How could I add a space to the beginning of every new line in Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I create a method that creates a space (" ") at the beginning of every new line used in a RichTextBox?

For example, in the textbox, I write:

`"This is
a really
cool test"`

How can I make it output:

`" This is
 a really
 cool test"`

I am not sure how I would go about doing this.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you adding the space to change how it appears on the screen? To give the impression of a margin?

Comment: Yes. Although, I don't intend it to act as a margin.

Comment: This is from three years ago, but seems to still apply even in .NET 4.5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914004/rich-text-box-padding-between-text-and-border-winforms-c-sharp based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rightmargin(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh, thank you. However, I need a physical space (" ") at the beginning of each new line. Not just the appearance. I apologize if I worded it incorrectly.

Comment: Can you achieve it manually without putting a carriage return at the end of each line? Can take advantage of a fixed width font, or is it a proportional font? Can there be mixed fonts in the box? Can the user paste text into the box?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, however, I need a physical space. It's not much about the appearance of the font itself.

Comment: Sorry that it took so long to reply, by the way.